¿Cómo continúo la ejecución del código después de un display() de IPython usado con una imagen de rdkit?
Estoy usando Google Colab, por lo que me encuentro en un Jupyter Notebook.
Estoy tratando de mostrar la estructura de un disacárido dados los nombres de los dos monosacáridos que la forman.
El problema ocurre cuando se muestran las estructuras con display(), pues la ejecución se queda ahí, sin mostrar lo que sigue en el código.
El código es el siguiente:
import requests
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from IPython.display import display
def obtener_smiles_pubchem(nombre):
    url = f"https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/name/{nombre}/property/CanonicalSMILES/JSON"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        smiles = data['PropertyTable']['Properties'][0]['CanonicalSMILES']
        return smiles
    else:
        print("No se encontró el compuesto.")
        return None

def mostrar_estructura(nombre_compuesto):
    if nombre_compuesto == "fructose":
        nombre_compuesto = nombre_compuesto.replace("fructose","beta-D-fructose")
    smiles = obtener_smiles_pubchem(nombre_compuesto)
    if smiles:
        print(f"SMILES de {nombre_compuesto}: {smiles}")
        mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)

        if mol:
            if mol.GetNumAtoms() > 0:
                print(f"La molécula de {nombre_compuesto} es la siguiente:\n")
                img = Draw.MolToImage(mol, size=(300, 300), kekulize=True)
                return display(img)
            else:
                return "La conversión del SMILES no generó una molécula válida."
        else:
            return "Error: No se pudo generar la estructura química desde el SMILES."
    else:
        return f"No se pudo obtener el SMILES para {nombre_compuesto}."
def ejercicio_6():
    datos_disacaridos = {"glucose + fructose":"sucrose", "fructose + glucose":"sucrose", "glucose + glucose":"maltose","glucose + galactose":"lactose"}
    while True:
        monosacarido_1 = input("\nIngrese el nombre del monosacárido 1 (en inglés): ").lower()
        mostrar_estructura(monosacarido_1)
        monosacarido_2 = input("\nIngrese el nombre del monosacárido 2 (en inglés): ").lower()
        mostrar_estructura(monosacarido_2)

        suma_monosacaridos = monosacarido_1 + " + " + monosacarido_2
        if suma_monosacaridos in datos_disacaridos.keys():
            disacarido = datos_disacaridos[suma_monosacaridos]
        else:
            print("Se desconoce el producto de los monosacáridos.")
            disacarido = input("\nIntroduzca el nombre del disacárido formado (en inglés): ").lower()
            datos_disacaridos[suma_monosacaridos] = disacarido
        mostrar_estructura(disacarido)

        cont = input("¿Desea ingresar otro par de monosacáridos? (s/n): ").lower()
        if cont not in ("s","si","sí"):
            print("Fin del ejercicio 6.")
            break

Un ejemplo de lo que ocurre:

Además, resulta que si primero se pide ingresar los nombres de los dos monosacáridos y luego se muestran las estructuras, entonces el código se puede ejecutar hasta mostrar la estructura del disacárido formado, pero ahí se vuelve a bloquear, pues ya no muestra el mensaje "¿Desea ingresar otro par de monosacáridos? (s/n):"
Algunas veces el código funciona como debe después de reiniciar la página del Colab, pero no siempre sucede. El código siempre debería funcionar.
ACTUALIZACIÓN: Modificación del código -> ¿Solución?
import requests
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from IPython.display import display
def obtener_smiles_pubchem(nombre):
    url = f"https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/name/{nombre}/property/CanonicalSMILES/JSON"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        # Obtener el SMILES
        smiles = data['PropertyTable']['Properties'][0]['CanonicalSMILES']
        return smiles
    else:
        print("No se encontró el compuesto.")
        return None

def mostrar_estructura(nombre_compuesto):
    if nombre_compuesto == "fructose":
        nombre_compuesto = nombre_compuesto.replace("fructose","beta-D-fructose")
    smiles = obtener_smiles_pubchem(nombre_compuesto)
    if smiles:
        print(f"SMILES de {nombre_compuesto}: {smiles}")
        mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)

        if mol:
          print(f"La molécula de {nombre_compuesto} es la siguiente:\n")
          display(Draw.MolToImage(mol, size=(300, 300), kekulize=True))
          return "Se mostró la estructura con éxito."
        else:
            return "Error: No se pudo generar la estructura química desde el SMILES."
    else:
        return f"No se pudo obtener el SMILES para {nombre_compuesto}."

def ingresar_monosacaridos():
  monosacarido_1 = input("\nIngrese el nombre del monosacárido 1 (en inglés): ").lower()
  monosacarido_2 = input("\nIngrese el nombre del monosacárido 2 (en inglés): ").lower()
  mostrar_estructura(monosacarido_1)
  mostrar_estructura(monosacarido_2)
  return monosacarido_1, monosacarido_2
def obtener_disacarido(suma_monosacaridos, datos_disacaridos):
  if suma_monosacaridos in datos_disacaridos.keys():
    disacarido = datos_disacaridos[suma_monosacaridos]
  else:
    print("Se desconoce el producto de los monosacáridos.")
    disacarido = input("\nIntroduzca el nombre del disacárido formado (en inglés): ").lower()
    datos_disacaridos[suma_monosacaridos] = disacarido
  mostrar_estructura(disacarido)
  return disacarido, datos_disacaridos
def ejercicio_6():
    datos_disacaridos = {"glucose + fructose":"sucrose", "fructose + glucose":"sucrose", "glucose + glucose":"maltose","glucose + galactose":"lactose"}
    while True:
        monosacarido_1, monosacarido_2 = ingresar_monosacaridos()
        suma_monosacaridos = monosacarido_1 + " + " + monosacarido_2
        disacarido, datos_disacaridos = obtener_disacarido(suma_monosacaridos, datos_disacaridos)
        cont = input("¿Desea ingresar otro par de monosacáridos? (s/n): ").lower()
        if cont not in ("s","si","sí"):
            print("Fin del ejercicio 6.")
            break
ejercicio_6()

Con esta modificación, se logra ejecutar el código, pero sin mostrar el "Se mostró la estructura con éxito." en mostrar_estructura(nombre_compuesto). Por suerte, esto no afecta el funcionamiento general, por lo que puede contar como "solución".

Podría ser algo del propio colab con alguna de las librerías gráficas. Probé el código en un notebook local y funcionó bien las 4 o 5 veces que lo ejecuté. Especifica en la pregunta una entrada o condición que siempre reproduzca el problema.

No entendí muy bien lo de especificar en la pregunta una entrada o condición, pero decidí modificar un poco el código y parece que ya está andando algo mejor tras separar las partes con display en funciones:
